# Error "java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Error parsing public key" with Java

Tags: java, android, aes, x509

I have to encrypt some data in my project. For this I'm using ECDH and AES-128-CBC.
The problem is:
I got the key from the other side. I have to create a public key from the mentioned key:

```
public PublicKey createPublicKey(byte[] key) {
   X509EncodedKeySpec x509key = new X509EncodedKeySpec(key);
   KeyFactory keyfactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
   return keyfactory.generatePublic(x509key);
}
```

But the code above returns an error:
**java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: Error parsing public key**

What am I doing wrong? Do the key need to have specified length? For now it's 32 bytes.

Comment: In what format did you got the key (pem file, der file, ..). You can try to look at the asn.1 data structure of the key at https://lapo.it/asn1js/ (the file  is not uploaded, but loaded and interpreted directly via JavaScript). Or you include the key in your question. As it is a public key this should not be a security problem.

Comment: Or just name the first two bytes, that's probably enough to identify the encoding of the key...